# React native: this.touchableHandleResponderGrant is not a function

Tags: javascript, react-native, drag, pan

I'm trying to implement a simple drag feature, by using the [React Native PanResponder](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/panresponder.html). I looked at [this tutorial](http://mindthecode.com/getting-started-with-the-panresponder-in-react-native/) but I'm making a much simpler thing, which just will change a state variable on drag.

```
componentWillMount() {
    this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
        onMoveShouldSetResponderCapture: () => true,
        onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => true,
        onPanResponderGrant: (e, gestureState) => {
            //this.setState({pan: 0});
            console.log('grant');
        },

        onPanResponderMove: (e, gestureState) => {
        //this.setState({pan: gestureState.dx});
        console.log(gestureState);
        },
        onPanResponderRelease: (e, {vx, vy}) => {
        }

    });
    console.log('pan init');
}
```

And in my render function I have this:

```
<Text {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}>Drag here</Text>
```

But as soon as I pan/drag i get a redbox with the error:

```
this.touchableHandleResponderGrant is not a function
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `panHandlers` prop can only be used with `View` or `Animated.View` component.

```
<View {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}>
  <Text>Drag here</Text>
</View>
```

or

```
<Animated.View {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}>
  <Text>Drag here</Text>
</Animated.View>
```

Comment: Ahh.. that's amazing, didn't have a clue about that. Now it works perfectly. Thank you so much! :)